# Editing questions to remove "thank you in advance" after reaching 2k reputation

Tags: discussion, edits

Will it be okay to remove "thank you" or "Hi, I am computer science student..."-like invocations from the question header/footer after reaching 2k reputation?

I saw threads on Meta about it, and the main conclusion was that it leaves a mess in suggested edit lists and wastes the time of the reviewers. I used to perform such edits and they were getting rejected because, as I was told, they didn't improve the question at all.

However, after reaching 2k reputation nobody will need to verify edits like these, so that's why I have doubts whether I should perform them in the future.

My question applies to minor edits (like fixing typos) as well.

Comment: It's fine and encouraged provided you fix everything else that's wrong in each post too.

Comment: @RobertLongson “provided you fix everything else that's wrong in each post too” So in the instance that there is nothing else in the post to edit it should be left alone? If only SO'ers doing the editing would follow that credo.